# ERROR whitelist rejection: phonegap 3.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

Newbie to phonegap and mobile programming. I'm getting the whitelist error when trying to connect to a localhost url http:// localhost/.

I've added access origin="*" to /appName/www/config.xml and /appName/platforms/ios/www/config.xml

I'm using phonegap 3.4 and the iphone simulator in xCode 5.1. From everything I've been reading, it should be working but isn't. I'm wondering if there is a setting in xCode that's causing the problem? If I open my local site in a browser, it works.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should set "OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView: YES" and
"ExternalHosts: *" in Cordova.plist file.

Comment: I'm using phonegap 3.4. From what I understand, the cordova.plist has been replaced with the config.xml.

Comment: There is no `localhost` on a device, because the device does not have a host service on it. You reference local files by path and name. `index.html` or `ccs/styles.css`

Comment: config.xml was introduced many versions ago, but who knows whether you still have to change .plist or not. But i actually didn't look carefully before: why do you try to connect to http://localhost? As Dawson Loudon mentioned, you should access application internal files using relative path

Comment: thx Dawson Loudon!! That was it. I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 and it worked. FYI. I will eventually be using ajax to connect to another website I have, but for now don't want to make changes to the production site. I want to make sure I can connect to a different site.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my below instruction try with anyone and let me know

> The following examples demonstrate whitelist syntax:
>
> Access to google.com:
>
> Access to the secure google.com
>   (https://):
>
> Access to the subdomain
>   maps.google.com:
>
> Access to all the
>   subdomains on google.com, for example mail.google.com and
>   docs.google.com:
>
> Access to all domains, for
>   example, google.com and developer.mozilla.org:

Comment: thanks for the help, but it was answered by Dawson Loudon. It's above in the comments.